# TabPageIndicator.scrollTo is not working

Tags: android, android-tabs

I want to implement interactive TabPageIndicatot in android. I am using ViewPager.TabPageIndicator to make object of indicator.I am trying to implement scrollTo in  TabPageIndicator class.

This is the code in my class. **indicator** is object of TabPageIndicator.

```
public void onPageScrolled(int pageNo, float arg1, final int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            indicator.scrollTo(arg2, 0);                                    
        }
```

This is the code in TabPageIndicator class.

```
private void animateToTab(final int x) {

     if (mTabSelector != null) {
         removeCallbacks(mTabSelector);
     }
     mTabSelector = new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
         //    final int scrollPos = tabView.getLeft() - (getWidth() - tabView.getWidth()) / 2;
             smoothScrollTo(x, 0);
             mTabSelector = null;
         }
     };
     post(mTabSelector);

}
 @Override
public void scrollTo(int x, int y) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.scrollTo(x, y);
    //Log.i("Hi", Integer.toString(x));
    animateToTab(x);
}
```

Here animateToTab() function is called infinite times. Why?

Comment: What do you mean by not working ? Be more specific.

Comment: It's called infinite times possibly due to `smoothScrollTo(x, 0)` causing the `scrollTo(x,y)` being called which then calls `smoothScrollTo(x, 0)` and thereby getting into an infinite loop (and quite possibly a StackOverflow exception). That's my best guess without having access to the entire call stack. Stick in a break point and verify if that's the case.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this. Can you please help me.